# Why content of folder deleted while restarting tomcat ? How to fix it

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, path, photo

Thanks in advance.
I created a web application that upload photo dynamically and I stored them locally at deployment path.
But while starting tomcat again it delete that folder and its content.
Is there any way to restore that content before restarting tomcat.

Comment: Is it Tomcat that purges your folder or does the web application do so on startup?

Comment: @rollstuhlfahrer Tomcat. That's why you're not supposed to store things there.